# php exec command does not work within ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, exec

I am using jQuery 2.0.2 with ajax to call a php page which executes a command to start a java client:

```
        $j(document).ready(function(){
            $j(".do_remote_sync").on("click",function(event) {                       
                var d = "";
                $j.ajax({
                    data: \'test=test2\',
                    type: \'POST\',
                    url: \'sync_remote.php\',
                    success: function(data) {
                        d = data;
                    }
                });                        
                //alert("after ajax");
            });
        });
```

The `sync_remote.php` page only contains following line:

```
exec("java -jar RemoteSync.jar config.properties", $output, $return_var);
```

The problem is now that the `sync_remote.php` page is **only** called if I write an "alert" command after the ajax call (`alert("after ajax");`).

If I comment out this line the ajax call is most probably not called!

The `sync_remote.php` page works without problems if a call it directly.

**Question**

Why the ajax call is not executed without the "alert" command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would happen if `.do_remote_sync` is a hyperlink.

Clicking the hyperlink navigates to its `href`, cancelling any active AJAX requests.
Adding an `alert()` gives the AJAX request enough time to make it to the server before that happens.

You need to `return false` to prevent the navigation.

Comment: It is a submit form element: <input class="do_remote_sync" type="submit" />. Does it behave the same like a hyperlink?

Comment: @sk2212: Yes; it submits the form.

Comment: Thats the problem! Thanks!